# PHPUnit: How to override and test a dependent method

Tags: unit-testing, phpunit

I am trying to use PHPUnit to write a test on a method of a class, Mail. The method I am testing is saveMessage( $arguments).  saveMessage, in addition to saving, may also call a class method, `$this->emailMessage( $arguments )`. I'd like to write a test that tests saveMessage, and tests that emailMessage is correctly called (with the correct arguments), but does NOT call the actual emailMessage method.

One way I could do it would be to subclass Mail, and override the emailMessage method. A more appealing way would be to Mock the Messages class, and override the emailMessage method, while testing the saveMessage method in the mocked object. However, then I would be testing the Mocked object itself; I've read that that is a bad idea, but I'm not entirely sure why, in this case. Is it safe to use a mock object for this purpose? Is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: I think your initial suggestion - to create a tester subclass of Mail is the easiest, and cleanest way to go.  Is there a reason you don't want to do this?  In your test, declare a static I_got_here variable initialized to FALSE, then in your overridden emailMessage function, set the I_got_here variable to true, and then back in your test, you assert that I_got_here is true.  Similarly, you could pass back arguments that were passed into your overridden emailMessage function.

Answer (score 0):

I think this falls under the category ["What to test and what not to test"](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/138987/do-i-need-to-test-everything) Without knowing the code this questions is hard to answer.

For instance why would the arguments *not* be correct? Are they manipulated? You could put the manipulating code in a method of its own and unit test that.

Or you could use [asserts](http://php.net/manual/en/function.assert.php) in your `saveMessage` method and just check in your unit test that no assertion errors are triggered.

From what I can tell this question is as much about the design of the code as it is about testing it.